# Car making a loud "clunk" noise after it's been off and sitting?

Tags: noise, hyundai, santa-fe

I know little to nothing about car maintenance, and I'm experiencing something odd with my wife's 2013 Hyundai Santa Fe.

When we come home in it and turn the car off and get off, maybe a minute or so afterwards the car makes a loud noise (it sounds like it comes from the rear section of the car).

The noise sounds like someone dropping a large stone against thick metal. Not the "clang" noise you'd normally expect from metal, but a much more muted quick noise.

That description may not be the best, but I'm struggling a bit trying to describe it.

Comment: are the doors all locked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you park, the exhaust system is very hot, but it quickly begins to cool.  As it does, the formerly hot components shrink relative to the car's body.  I'd guess the exhaust pipe is slipping on something as it shortens.  If the sound is not metallic, that may be because there are sound-deadening components built into the system.

Comment: Just to add, this is not talking about "tiny" changes. The total length of the exhaust expands by a few millimeters from cold to hot. That's why it is not rigidly bolted onto the car, but suspended on hangers. Possibly, one of the hangers is "jumping" back into position and making the sound. It may also be coming from a heat shield cooling down, not the actual exhaust pipe.

Answer (score -1):

Do you apply the parking brake? Could be this getting stuck and pulling of the disc as you pull away